# Clickhouse pass data for inner join

Tags: clickhouse

In PostgreSQL we can join tables with custom data.

For example:

```
select * 
from points p 
inner join (VALUES (5, '2000-1-1'::date, 1, 1)) as x(id, create_date, store_id, supplier_id)
on p.id = x.id
```

Does such kind of join exist in Clickhouse? If yes, how should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/5984

```
SELECT *
FROM VALUES('a UInt64, s String', (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'))

┌─a─┬─s─────┐
│ 1 │ one   │
│ 2 │ two   │
│ 3 │ three │
└───┴───────┘

WITH 
    [(toUInt64(1), 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')] AS rows_array, 
    arrayJoin(rows_array) AS row_tuple
SELECT 
    row_tuple.1 AS number_decimal, 
    row_tuple.2 AS number_string
┌─number_decimal─┬─number_string─┐
│              1 │ one           │
│              2 │ two           │
│              3 │ three         │
└────────────────┴───────────────┘
```